# How do I calculate the change in the y variable for one std increase in the x variable?

Tags: regression, standard-deviation, z-score

Some studies report the regression results and when explaining it, they say something like " a one standard deviation in the x variable increases the y variable by something" How do we run this model in a statistical software? Do we simply to the Z-score transformation and re-run the original model again?

Answer (score 2):

The regression coefficient gives the change in $y$ for a one-unit change in the feature. That is, multiply the coefficient by $1$.

How many units is one standard deviation of that feature? Multiply by that value instead of $1$.

For instance, if you have a model $\hat y = 3 - 2x$, and $x$ has a standard deviation of $4$, when $x$ changes by one standard deviation, $x$ changes by $4$, so $\hat y$ changes by $2\times 4 = 8$.

Answer (score 0):

I see two easy ways:

1. Standardization, i.e. z-transforming your explanatory variable
   $x$ before running the regression will allow you to interpret its
   coefficient as expected increase in $y$ if $x$ increases by one
   standard deviation.
2. Multiply the coefficient for (untransformed) $x$ by the standard deviation of $x$.